# Trouble Installing JetBrains IDE Support in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm having some trouble installing JetBrains IDE Support for Chrome.  The browser is claiming: `This application is not supported on this computer. Installation has been disabled.`

Has anyone had similar problems?

Alex

Comment: What is your Chrome version? JetBrains IDE Support extension 1.11 requires Chromium 27

Comment: Hi Lena, that worked! If you want to put it down as an answer, I'll upvote it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you lena, that worked! For all others with a similar problem, check

`Chrome->About Google Chrome`

to view your Chrome version.  If lower than 27, uninstall and reinstall the latest version from https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/ and try installing again (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji/details?hl=en).